# how to access php.ini file of server?

Tags: file-upload, file-permissions, php

My application was working fine, I dont know what happened suddenly image upload function stoped functioning.It gives this error-

```
URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in D:\Hosting\6448289\html\upload.php on line 112
```

for any file access `allow_url_fopen` must be `ON` but this is `OFF` now. 
if you open this link - [www.shizin.com/phpinfo.php](http://localhost/shizin/phpinfo.php)

you can see that `allow_url_fopen` is `OFF`. My hosting compny is GoDaddy.com.
**How and Where I can access php.ini file of my project so that I can set  it ON  or is there any php commands that can be run to set this permission ON.Please suggest.**

Comment: Have you considered rewriting your code so it does not depend on such feature? I see little reason to make an HTTP request from the server in order to upload a file :-?

Comment: what? sorry I didn't get you.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have a custom php.ini or php5.ini file somewhere in your account. Launch your FTP client and find it.

Found via Google:

- http://community.godaddy.com/godaddy/tips-for-protecting-your-php-based-website/
- http://community.godaddy.com/help/article/5647

Comment: no its not there I have searched.Can I upload my localhost php.ini file to my ftp account.But where shoul I copy that.

Comment: Have you read the links I provided? Have you tried the `phpinfo()` trick described in the second one?